# Input file containing character % breaks printf in awk

Tags: awk

This simple awk script prints each line of a file using `printf`, adding some text before and after it.

```
{ printf("Line %i:\t" $0 "<br>\n", NR); }
```

It runs as expected on almost any input file, except if the file contains a character sequence like "%d" or "%i" that breaks the `printf` function, returning the error (I'm running gawk):

```
Fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string.
```

I can work around this error by first running sed to replace the character "%" with some wildcard, piping the output to awk and then piping it again to sed to revert the change, but that is obviously an ugly solution.

Note, this example is somewhat artificial and simplistic, I could do the same thing differently, using different tools. However, it is an awk problem that I do not know how to solve (in a more elegant way than using sed).

Comment: So print $0 as it is not inside format string... `printf "%s", $0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string you want to print, you shouldn't pass it as a format argument to printf. Instead use `%s` printf format specifier:

```
{ printf "Line %i:\t%s<br>\n", NR, $0 }
```